# Django submitting form action based on what was selected

Tags: jquery, html, django

I'm pretty new to Django and web development in general so I'm still trying to conceptualize a lot of these ideas.

What I'm having a hard time understanding is how to properly handle an HTML form action attribute upon clicking a "submit" button, based on what was chosen in select/dropdown boxes I have set up.

For example, If a user were to select a car (or trim in my example below) in a dropdown box, then clicked the go button, I would want to then send the user to a new page with information about the car trim. Here is what I have:

**Template**

```html
 <!-- Bar of dropdowns for searching. -->
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <form action="" method="get" class="form-inline" id="dropdownText">
   <div class="form-group" id="dropdownGroup">

    <span style="display:inline-block" class="selectBox">
     <select class="form-control" id="make">
      <option value='empty'></option>
      <!-- List each make's name. -->
      {% for make in allMakes %}
      <option value="{{ make.id }}">{{ make.name }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
     </select>
     <label for="make" style="display:block">Make</label>
    </span>

    <span style="display:inline-block" class="selectBox">
     <select class="form-control" id="model" disabled>
      <!-- List each make's model's name. -->
     </select>
     <label for="model" style="display:block">Model</label>
    </span>

    <span style="display:inline-block" class="selectBox">
     <select class="form-control" id="trim" disabled>
      <!-- List all trims for each make/model. -->
     </select>
     <label for="trim" style="display:block">Trim</label>
    </span>

   </div>
  </form>
  <form action="" id="trimDetail">
   <div class="text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="go">GO!</button>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
```

**What it looks like**

http://puu.sh/phaHG/105ed07b28.png

**DetailView for the car trim**

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Trim
    template_name = 'search/detail.html'
```

**URL that will correspond to the view**

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', DetailView.as_view(model=Trim,
template_name='search/detail.html')),
```

Upon selecting the trim and clicking go, the page is simply refreshed with the url changing to:

"/?trimId=4"

, the trimId changing based on what the user selected, but not sending them to the template that will display the information for the id.

I can make this work by simply changing the form action using jQuery upon clicking the button, but i wasn't sure if this was bad practice, and I want to learn the proper Django way of doing it.

**My jQuery way of doing it:**

```
var $elTrim = $('select#trim'); // The trim select box.
var $trimForm = $('form#trimDetail'); // The form around the button.

function updateAction(){

    if($elTrim.find('option:selected').val() != 'empty'){
        $trimForm.attr('action', $elTrim.val());
    }

}

$elTrim.change(updateAction);
```

Comment: I've added the way I did it using jQuery, but I wasn't sure if this was the "correct" way of doing it or if it was not good practice. I was not aware that this is not a Django type of problem.

Comment: Oh, I was confused as to what you were asking, as you could have clicked the "run snippet" to see the HTML ...

Comment: not it doesn't work. Stackoverflow run snippet does not render django tmplates

Comment: Ah, sorry I was a bit confused. I've fixed the HTML back to match the JS anyway however. Is there anything that doesn't make sense that I could clarify on?

Comment: thanks for adding back the django template. What I asked for was the rendered HTML (Also known as what you see in the browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a good way of doing it. Your search page should always submit to the same place; that page can then be responsible for either showing the results directly, or redirecting you to the relevant page that does.

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand what you mean. What is selected the "trim" box on the search page changes the form action of the button which will then be able to go to the correct URL for the ID that was chosen. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I told you. Send the form to a single "search" page, and in that view redirect to the "trim" page passing that ID.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I've just got to figure out how to properly do that. I've been struggling understanding how views work and interact with the template/URLs, especially in regards to "get" and "post", and function based vs. classes.